# Update all array keys using value from another array

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to replace all numerical keys in `$aValues` with a textual equivalent stored in `$aKeyNames`.

```
$aKeyNames = array(0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar');
$aValues = array(0 => 'foo content', 1 => 'bar content');
```

The desired output;

```
$aValues = array('foo' => 'foo content', 'bar' => 'bar content');
```

To achieve this I've written the following working code;

```
foreach ($aValues as $iPos => $aValue) {
    $aValues[ $aKeyNames[$iPos] ] = $aValue; 
    unset($aValues[$iPos]);
}
```

My concern is that `$aValues` is very large. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Comment: Your solutions seems good, since you want to replace the key by the value of the same key in the other array. You can use `array_combine()`, but you have to make sure both arrays are sorted the same, so the keys are in the same order.

Comment: array_combine is the best way to do it, if you have same keys in both array.  have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Comment: thank you for the comments, Ive just realised a mistake in what I've posted, am just working on an updated question

Comment: Please accept my apologies, I've updated my question so it now uses a multidimensional array

Comment: That's a completely different question. You should roll back as now the correct answers don't make any sense any more.

Comment: ok I can appreciate that, should i remove the question and start a new one?

Comment: You can't delete as there are answers with upvotes. But a new question makes sense.

Comment: ok thanks, should I flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: I don't think so, the original question with the original answers might help someone.

Comment: Just revert your changes and start a new question.

Comment: ok will revert to original and accept answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to manual for [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine):

```
print_r(array_combine($aKeyNames, $aValues));
```

Comment: Here comes silent donwvoter.

Comment: I would love to know why this was down voted, since it seem to do exactly what the OP asks for? Not helpful to just down vote without any comment.

Comment: I'm curious as to why this is downvoted. The only difference I can see is that the OP's code is limited to 2 arrays and the used values are unset in the loop. Lower memory footprint?