# Update all array keys in multidimensional array using value from another array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to replace all numerical keys in the multidimensional array `$aValues` with a textual equivalent stored in `$aKeyNames`.

```
$aKeyNames = array(0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar');
$aValues = array( 
    0 => array( 0 => 'content relating to foo', 1 => 'content relating to bar' ), 
    1 => array( 0 => 'content relating to foo', 1 => 'content relating to bar') 
);
```

The desired output;

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'foo' => string 'content relating to foo' (length=23)
      'bar' => string 'content relating to bar' (length=23)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'foo' => string 'content relating to foo' (length=23)
      'bar' => string 'content relating to bar' (length=23)
```

To achieve this I've written the following working code;

```
foreach ($aValues as $iValuePos => $aValue) {
    foreach ($aValue as $iKey => $sTempValue){
        $aValues[$iValuePos][ $aKeyNames[$iKey] ] = $sTempValue;
        unset($aValues[$iValuePos][$iKey]);
    }
}
```

My concern is that `$aValues` is very large. Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Please note this question is different to the one provided as a duplicate due to the use of a multidimensional array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update all array keys using value from another array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38078649/update-all-array-keys-using-value-from-another-array)

Comment: This question is clearly different to that one (being my last question). As suggested on that thread I have created a new one! Thanks for not taking the time to read and marking as a duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't bench-marked but it should be faster:

```
$aValues = array_map(function($v) use ($aKeyNames) {
                         return array_combine($aKeyNames, $v);
                     }, $aValues);
```

Another alternative using a reference `&` to the value:

```
foreach($aValues as &$v) {
    $v = array_combine($aKeyNames, $v);
}
```

Comment: looks good, going to benchmark with the other answer and will post back

Comment: getting an error back off this; `array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements`

Comment: Which they do in your question.  Maybe your real arrays are not what you show?

Comment: yeah spot on. This answer came out slightly faster than the one below. Thank you

Comment: It's about which is better not faster.  Mine was actually slightly later than the other one.

Comment: Thats interesting, could it be a large value stored against the key increases the time? The benchmark has come out with this on top, then mine then Sinkai. I wouldn't imagine its the case. Do take your point too, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$aKeyNames = array(0 => 'foo', 1 => 'bar');

$aValues = array( 
    0 => array( 0 => 'content relating to foo', 1 => 'content relating to bar' ), 
    1 => array( 0 => 'content relating to foo', 1 => 'content relating to bar') 
);

foreach ($aValues as $iValuePos => $aValue) {
    $aValues[$iValuePos] = array_combine($aKeyNames, $aValue);
}
```

Comment: thats great thank you! Will run a quick test using the data set and post back timings